# Python numpy methods/attributes faster than numpy functions?

Tags: python, function, performance, numpy, methods

I recently noticed that some `numpy` array attributes/methods seem to be significantly faster than the corresponding `numpy` functions. Example for `np.conj(x)` vs. `x.conjugate()`:

```
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(100)

t0_1 = 0
t0_2 = 0
for i in range(1000):
    a = np.random.rand(10000)
    t0 = time.time()
    b = np.conjugate(a)
    t0_1 += time.time() - t0; t0 = time.time()
    c = a.conjugate()
    t0_2 += time.time() - t0; t0 = time.time()

print(t0_1, t0_2)

# example output times: 0.01222848892211914 0.0008714199066162109
```

Even without proper benchmarks, it looks like there is a performance gain of more than a factor of 10. Similarly, it seems that also `x.real, x.imag, x.max()` and other basic methods are faster than the corresponding functions `np.real(x), np.imag(x), np.max(x)` etc.

Can somebody explain to me where the time saving comes from? Does it have to do with in-place operations vs. new array creation? Are there certain checks that the `numpy` functions do which are skipped for the array methods? Thank you in advance!

**Update:** Below is a simple comparison of computation times for several common `numpy` functions/methods, for float, complex and boolean arrays. The largest speed gain factors of methods over functions (float/complex/bool) appear to be for `a.real` (12/15/12), `a.imag`(70/15/26) and `a.conj`(80/15/33), as explained by the post of @hpaulj (`imag` and `conj` are not useful for real arrays though), and for `a.sort` (5/5/1.5) (my guess is that this is due to in-place operations), `a.max/a.min` (1.6 for bool) (again, `max` and `min` are not useful for bool arrays). Other speed gains are typically between 1.1 and 1.4. For `a.argsort`, `a.std` and `a.__len__`, the factors are often around 1, for `a.__abs__` even below 1.

So it looks like except for `a.real`, `a.imag` and `a.sort`, the speed gains are often not too large, say 1.2. However, this may depend on array sizes, whether the array is (partially) sorted or not, etc.

```
import numpy as np
from IPython import get_ipython

ipython = get_ipython()

np.random.seed(1000)

asize = 10000
dtype_list = ['float', 'complex', 'bool']
for i in range(3):
    print(dtype_list[i])
    print('-----------------')
    if i == 0:
        a = np.random.rand(asize)
    elif i == 1:
        a = np.random.rand(asize) + 1j*np.random.rand(asize)
    elif i == 2:
        a = np.random.randint(2,size=asize).astype(bool)
    
    function_list = [np.real, np.imag, np.conj, np.sum, np.cumsum, np.prod, np.cumprod,
                     np.max, np.min, np.argmax, np.argmin, np.mean, np.var, np.std,
                     np.sort, np.argsort, np.all, np.any, np.abs, len]
    methatt_list = [a.real, a.imag, a.conj, a.sum, a.cumsum, a.prod, a.cumprod,
                    a.max, a.min, a.argmax, a.argmin, a.mean, a.var, a.std,
                    a.sort, a.argsort, a.all, a.any, a.__abs__, a.__len__]
    for j in range(len(function_list)):
        print(function_list[j].__name__)
        ipython.magic('timeit function_list[j](a)')
        if callable(methatt_list[j]):
            ipython.magic('timeit methatt_list[j]()')
        else:
            ipython.magic('timeit methatt_list[j]')
    print('')

# float
# -----------------
# real
# 740 ns ± 13.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 60.7 ns ± 0.226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# imag
# 4.45 µs ± 36.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 60.9 ns ± 0.353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# conjugate
# 9.64 µs ± 40.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 124 ns ± 0.238 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# sum
# 15.8 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 11.8 µs ± 82.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# cumsum
# 42.4 µs ± 254 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 37.7 µs ± 38.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# prod
# 32.7 µs ± 144 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 29 µs ± 57.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# cumprod
# 51.5 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 47.1 µs ± 154 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# amax
# 14.5 µs ± 51.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 10.7 µs ± 61.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# amin
# 14.6 µs ± 90.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 10.7 µs ± 45.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# argmax
# 11.1 µs ± 15.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 8.62 µs ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# argmin
# 11.5 µs ± 31.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 8.76 µs ± 37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# mean
# 23.5 µs ± 440 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 19.6 µs ± 569 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# var
# 78.6 µs ± 381 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 73.3 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# std
# 86.7 µs ± 120 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 81.9 µs ± 663 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# sort
# 659 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 141 µs ± 682 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# argsort
# 156 µs ± 508 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 151 µs ± 704 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# all
# 23.4 µs ± 41.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 17.7 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# any
# 23.4 µs ± 72.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 17.3 µs ± 67 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# absolute
# 7.1 µs ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 7.25 µs ± 20.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# len
# 125 ns ± 0.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# 117 ns ± 0.463 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# complex
# -----------------
# real
# 920 ns ± 1.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 61.1 ns ± 0.0517 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# imag
# 898 ns ± 0.792 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 61.3 ns ± 0.178 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# conjugate
# 18.1 µs ± 45.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 18.6 µs ± 7.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# sum
# 24 µs ± 40 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 18.7 µs ± 97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# cumsum
# 44.8 µs ± 80.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 39.4 µs ± 135 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# prod
# 99.6 µs ± 195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 95.4 µs ± 108 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# cumprod
# 94.9 µs ± 245 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 89.7 µs ± 284 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# amax
# 41.3 µs ± 141 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 37 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# amin
# 41.7 µs ± 65.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 37.1 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# argmax
# 27.4 µs ± 47.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 24.5 µs ± 77.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# argmin
# 28.8 µs ± 28.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 25.5 µs ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# mean
# 32.2 µs ± 43.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 27.6 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# var
# 139 µs ± 844 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 135 µs ± 476 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# std
# 147 µs ± 195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 145 µs ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# sort
# 774 µs ± 3.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 201 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# argsort
# 277 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 271 µs ± 123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# all
# 37.9 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 31 µs ± 252 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# any
# 37.5 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 30.2 µs ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# absolute
# 217 µs ± 2.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 216 µs ± 272 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# len
# 121 ns ± 0.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# 117 ns ± 1.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# bool
# -----------------
# real
# 726 ns ± 4.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 60.5 ns ± 0.0926 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# imag
# 1.55 µs ± 2.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 60.7 ns ± 0.123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# conjugate
# 4.16 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 125 ns ± 0.339 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# sum
# 24.2 µs ± 82.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 19.3 µs ± 82.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# cumsum
# 48.2 µs ± 428 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 41.2 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# prod
# 29.2 µs ± 73.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 25.3 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# cumprod
# 53.7 µs ± 83.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 46.6 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# amax
# 9.37 µs ± 93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 5.81 µs ± 21.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# amin
# 9.16 µs ± 15.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 5.75 µs ± 14.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# argmax
# 2.93 µs ± 8.85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 589 ns ± 5.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# argmin
# 3.07 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 622 ns ± 4.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# mean
# 33.5 µs ± 27.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 29.1 µs ± 286 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# var
# 111 µs ± 749 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 105 µs ± 735 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# std
# 117 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 113 µs ± 409 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# sort
# 157 µs ± 407 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 105 µs ± 433 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# argsort
# 115 µs ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 112 µs ± 925 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# all
# 8.26 µs ± 9.85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 3.86 µs ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# any
# 8.49 µs ± 23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 4 µs ± 30.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# absolute
# 1.52 µs ± 3.14 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# 1.72 µs ± 2.95 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
# len
# 122 ns ± 0.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
# 117 ns ± 0.279 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I will guess that there is some overhead when you use the function.

Comment: Yes, but it appears to be much larger than I would have expected (i.e. much larger than the time for the operation itself)...

Answer (score 4):

`numpy` functions often delegate the action to a method, if it exists.  But they must also check that the argument is an array, and so on.  `ufuncs` also have some extra 'baggage' that handles parameters like `out`, `where`.  So time differences don't (necessarily) scale with array size.

```
In [400]: a = np.random.rand(10000)
```

Comparing `conjugate`:

```
In [404]: timeit np.conjugate(a)
10 µs ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [405]: timeit a.conjugate()
94.2 ns ± 1.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

That `ns` time suggests that the method is taking some sort of shortcut.  (I'll explore that later)

`max` time difference isn't as significant, which I can attribute to the function overhead:

```
In [406]: timeit np.max(a)
13.2 µs ± 16.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [407]: timeit a.max()
9.46 µs ± 79.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But let's test with a complex array, where `conjugate` isn't trivial

```
In [408]: ac = a+1j*a
```

Now the method and function time the same:

```
In [409]: timeit np.conjugate(ac)
18.2 µs ± 14.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [410]: timeit ac.conjugate()
18.3 µs ± 10.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `real` attribute is still much faster.  Looking at the python code for `np.real` I think the time difference is just due to the function wrapper.

```
In [411]: timeit np.real(ac)
743 ns ± 21.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [413]: timeit ac.real
129 ns ± 4.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

The `conjugate` method for a float array just returns a view (or maybe the array itself).  That accounts for its speed:

```
In [418]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[418]: (84672384, False)
In [419]: a.conjugate().__array_interface__['data']
Out[419]: (84672384, False)
In [420]: ac.__array_interface__['data']
Out[420]: (84992432, False)
In [421]: ac.conjugate().__array_interface__['data']
Out[421]: (85165216, False)
```

It's the array itself:

```
In [422]: id(a)
Out[422]: 140673862490512
In [423]: id(a.conjugate())
Out[423]: 140673862490512
```

`np.real` code:

```
def real(val):
    try:
        return val.real
    except AttributeError:
        return asanyarray(val).real
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. So for `a.conjugate()` some speed is saved due to giving a view of the array and for `a.real` it skips the try-except statement. But is there some kind of rule of thumb when to use the array methods and when to use the numpy functions? In a quite more complex program I replaced the functions `np.real(a), np.imag(a), np.conj(a), np.max(a), np.argmax(a), np.argsort(a)` and `np.copy(a)` with their method counterparts, resulting in a speed boost to ~80% of the function-based computation time (a factor of ~1.25).